# How to change project number for the Imagen Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I filled Trusted Tester Program form to get access to Imagen in Vertex AI. I got access but when I filled the wrong project number in the "Get Started" tab. I am not finding any option to change the provided project number. How can I change it?

Did google search but couldn't find any lead.

Comment: I don't think stack overflow is going to be able to help you in this case. You could try reaching out to the program's contact email (if there is one) or the trusted tester mailing list.